# Matches in the new RegexBuddy 4

Tags: php, regex

RegexBuddy usually works perfectly for me. 
RB4 just came out and I downloaded the demo.

http://yu8.us/rbdemo

Testing it, I am having a problem I didn't have in RB3. I am sure I am missing something obvious and wonder if it may jump out at someone else.

In PHP mode, Match mode, Test mode, I have this pattern (a basic pattern to test some features in a simple password):

```
^(?=\w{6,10}$)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d).*$
```

In the subject window, I have this:

```
adfA899
9_PP098kk
sadfa88U
```

But nothing seems to match. In RB3, all three are highlighted.
I also tried matching literals (e.g. "horse") but no cigar.

Nothing urgent but if someone else is configuring RB4 I'd love to know what I'm missing.

Comment: Well, I wont comment about RB since i'm not an RB user, but what I can say, is that is an awefull expression, no wonder it's not working... If you want to have a solution for your regex, please make clear what is the *input* and the *expected output*...

Comment: I don't know whats wrong, but the `.*.*` is redundant.

Comment: @Enissay, apart from the duplicated dot-star (now edited out), there's nothing wrong with the pattern. It's just a string of lookaheads to make sure a tested string conforms (must have at least one uppercase etc.) But that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured it out. It was indeed very silly.

There's a "highlight" control that highlights the matches.
In RB3, I always had it turned on, so I had forgotten that it could even be off.
When I installed RB4, it was off by default. The subject was being matched, but it wasn't being highlighted, so I thought it wasn't matching.

All good now.

Thanks for your help, you all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you select <kbd>^$ match at line breaks</kbd>? It activates the multiline mode. Otherwise, `^` and `$` only matches at the beginning and the end of the string respectively.